# Restrict subfolder to access parent

Tags: php, apache, root, subdirectory

Is it in possible to somehow make sure a subdirectory can not access files or other directories which are located in it's parent directory , or above ( in any way, this includes PHP scripts ).

I have asked a similar question before, and the answer was to edit the httpd.conf, but sadly my hosting does not allow me to change it.

Also another programmer told suggested me to use open_basedir, and also that is locked on my hosting.

Is there any other way of accomplishing this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: htaccess will do the trick, check it out

Comment: @Jon - thanks for mental nudge. Comment removed.

Comment: In short: no, not without the access to the http configuration (using a different user for running those scripts, `open_basedir`, another vhost, or a combination of those) you clearly aren't getting with your current host.

Comment: Check if your hosting allows you to create directories outside the www (public folder) and use that folder to store all files you want to protect.